# Почему вложенный класс не объявляется другом?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, класс

Внутреннему классу MyIterator нужно получить доступ к приватному полю `RBTree<T,R> tree`, лежащему во внешнем классе Map:

```
template<class T,class R>
class Map 
{
    friend class MyIterator;

public:
    Map();
    ~Map();
    R& operator[](T index)
    {
        return tree.searchOperator(index);
    }
class MyIterator : public iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, RBTNode<T, R>>
    {

        public:
        MyIterator(RBTNode<T, R> it)
        {
            second = it.Element.second;
            first = it.Element.first;

        }
        MyIterator()
        {

        }
        MyIterator& operator=(const MyIterator& it) 
        {

        }
        MyIterator& operator*()
        {
            //пустует. 

        }
        MyIterator(const MyIterator& source)
        {
            first = source.first;
            second = source.second;
        }
        MyIterator operator++(int) 
        {//Post ++

            RBTNode<T, R>* pt = tree.search(first);
            pt =tree.Inc(pt);
            //MyIterator tmp = *this;
            *this.first=pt.Element.first;
            *this.second = pt.Element->second;
            return *this;
        }
        MyIterator operator->()
        {
            //
            return (**this);
        }

    public:
        T first;
        R second;
    };

    MyIterator begin()
    {
        RBTNode<T, R> pt = tree.f_begin();
        MyIterator temp(pt);

        return temp;
    }

private:
     RBTree<T,R> tree;//хочу сделать доступным в MyIterator
    //RBTNode<T, R> tempnode;
};

template <class T,class R>
Map<T, R>::Map() {


}
template <class T, class R>
Map<T,R>::~Map()
{

}
```

Кого и как объявить другом,чтобы эта перегрузка имела доступ к экземпляру дерева?

```
        MyIterator operator++(int) 
        {//Post ++
            RBTNode<T, R>* pt = tree.search(first);//Ошибка tree идентификатор не найден
            pt =tree.Inc(pt);
            //MyIterator tmp = *this;
            *this.first=pt.Element.first;
            *this.second = pt.Element->second;
            return *this;
        }
```

Comment: Вы хотите получить доступ к внутреннему объекту не имея доступа к объекту который его содержит? Но это же бред... У вас поле `tree` содержится в `Map`, а работаете вы с `MyIterator`.

Comment: Никого не нужно объявлять другом. Вложенный класс и так является "другом" охватывающего класса. При чем здесь "друзья" и зачем вы и[ упоминаете не понятно вообще - никакого отношения к вашей ошибке они не имеют. Что такое `tree` внутри `MyIterator`? Это `tree` какого экземпляра `Map`?

Comment: "Кого и как объявить другом,чтобы эта перегрузка имела доступ к экземпляру дерева?" - к **какому** экземпляру дерева??? У вас нет никакого "экземпляра дерева" внутри `operator++`.

Comment: @AnT, RBTree<T,R> это класс красно-чёрного дерева, его экземпляр хранится в Map

Comment: Еще раз: в каком именно экземпляре `Map` хранится это `tree`? К какому экземпляру `Map` вы хотите обратиться???

Comment: @AnT, но экземпляр есть во внешнем классе, почему он не доступен во вложенном?

Comment: @AnT, Map<int,string> mymap; например в этом

Comment: Это как это? Экземпляры не бывают в "классах". Класс - это просто тип.  Экземпляр данных может быть только в *объекте* класса. У вашего оператора `operator ++` нет на руках никаких объектов `Map`. Откуда ему взять `tree`?

Comment: Ну так тогда та и пишите: `mymap.tree`.

Comment: @AnT, мне нужно,чтобы дерево осталось private

Comment: Так оно и останется `private`. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Elvin, Оно и так останется приватным... Передайте указатель или ссылку на `Map` вашему итератору что бы он знал откуда ему брать объект...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вложенные объявления классов ничем не отличаются он невложенных объявлений классов, кроме схемы именования и того, что вложенный класс имеет *право* доступа ко всем членам охватывающего класса. Во всем остальном это совершенно самостоятельные, независимые классы.

Ваш класс (шаблон) `Map::MyIterator` - это совершенно независимый класс. Поле `tree` является членом класса `Map` и доступ к полю `tree` возможен только через конкретный экземпляр класса `Map`. У вас в методе `Map::MyIterator::operator ++` нет никакого экземпляра класса `Map`. Поэтому и никакого `tree` нет тоже.

Если вы хотите, чтобы `Map::MyIterator` был привязан к конкретному экземпляру класса `Map` и брал оттуда член `tree`, то вам эту связь придется организовывать самостоятельно вручную. Тот факт, что `Map::MyIterator` объявлен внутри `Map` абсолютно никак вам в этом не помогает, кроме предоставления вышеупомянутого права доступа.

Comment: как такое можно организовать, не прибегая к экземпляру класса Map?